# PHP Search Sub-Directory for a specific file

Tags: php, html

I've been looking a solution to my problem. I have a website that has many files in many sub-directories (all in one main directory). I need a search function that can search part of a name of a file and return it back. I need the function to not be case sensitive (i.e. if the file name is ALL CAPS and user searches with lower case then it should still find the file). The function I have below only works for 1 directory and does not work recursively.

Please help me modify my code to work with multiple directories.

```
<?php
$dirname = "./OFFICE PRECEDENTS/";//Directory to search in. *Must have a trailing slash*
$findme = $_POST["search"];

$dir = opendir($dirname);

while(false != ($file = readdir($dir))){   
    //Loop for every item in the directory.
    if(($file != ".") and ($file != "..") and ($file != ".DS_Store") and ($file != "search.php"))
    {
        //Exclude these files from the search
        $pos = stripos($file, $findme);
        if ($pos !== false){
           $thereisafile = true;//Tell the script something was found.
           //Display the search results as links.
           echo'<a href="' . $dirname . $file . '">' . $file . '</a><br>';
        }else{
            //Leave this blank
        }
    }
}

if (!isset($thereisafile)){
    echo "Nothing was found.";//Tell the user nothing was found.
    echo '<img src="yourimagehere.jpg"/>';//Display an image, when nothing was found.
}
?>
```

Comment: you check wheter the file is dir or not before you are searching your string: `if (is_dir($file)) //search again`

Comment: Have a look at the glob() function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php. Look at the Contributor Notes for other peoples solutions.

Comment: jeff can you possibly help amend my code to incorporate the glob() function? my head is not in the programming mode lol... your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
<?php
//--- get all the directories
$dirname = '';
$findme  = "*.php";
$dirs    = glob($dirname.'*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
$files   = array();
//--- search through each folder for the file
//--- append results to $files
foreach( $dirs as $d ) {
    $f = glob( $d .'/'. $findme );
    if( count( $f ) ) {
        $files = array_merge( $files, $f );
    }
}
if( count($files) ) {
    foreach( $files as $f ) {
        echo "<a href='{$dirname}/{$f}'>{$f}</a><br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "Nothing was found.";//Tell the user nothing was found.
    echo '<img src="yourimagehere.jpg"/>';//Display an image, when nothing was found.
}
?>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Firstly I need to get entries from $_POST as this function is searching using a search box. Secondly the function cannot find the file

Comment: Did you make the necessary alterations to the code of $dirname and $findme?

Comment: Yes I did. The directory that I want to search is only one level up. (i.e. ./OFFICE PRECEDENTS/) but when I enter that redirects to /OFFICE PRECEDENTS/OFFICE PRECEDENTS so it duplicates the directory name in the linking. Also how would I integrate stripos() function?

Answer (score 0):

@fixnode

Get rid of the `{$dirname}` and it should work fine. Also modify, `$findme  = "[Fix]*.pdf";` to look for keywords instead of exact filenames (case sensitive).